# Nest API - APIError: blocked - Using Python Package

Tags: python, python-requests, nest-api, home-automation

I'm using the Nest API to poll the current temperature and related temperature data from two of my Nests (simultaneously).

I was initially polling this data every minute but started getting an error:

**nest.nest.APIError: blocked**

I don't get the error every minute, more like intermittently every 5-10 minutes.

Reading through [their documentation](https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/data-rate-limits/) it seems that while pulling data once per minute is permissible, it's the maximum recommended query frequency.

*So I set it to two minutes.* I'm still getting the error.

I'm using this [Python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-nest/3.2.0), although I'm starting to wonder if there's too much going on under the hood that is making unnecessary requests.

Has anyone had any experience with this type of Nest error, or this Python package before?

Does polling two Nests with the same authenticated call result in multiple requests, as it relates to their data limiting?

**Should I just scrap this package and roll my own?** *(this is generally my preference, but I need to learn to stop always re-writing everything the moment I hit a snag like this in order to fully control and thoroughly understand each aspect of a particular integration, right?)*

Comment: The rate limit for polling typically sits at around 180 GET calls per hour and 10 PUT calls per hour. Blocked is almost always a rate limit error, but you can confirm if its an HTTP 429 returned.

Comment: I scrapped the package I was using and wrote the (relatively simple) integration myself so I can be absolutely positive i'm within those limits. Will update here with more information

Comment: This problem was fixed by getting rid of the Python Nest package and writing a fresh integration. I can confirm I can pull at least once per minute without any issues.